# Can you debug PhoneGap using Eclipse?

Tags: android, eclipse, debugging, cordova

Right now I'm using the PhoneGap cloud based builder to create my Android packages.

Is it possible to build my project locally using Eclipse, and then deploy to the device while using the Eclipse debugger?

My understanding is that you can download an Android buildable version of PhoneGap, and make your own builds.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See the latest [getting started with Android](http://docs.phonegap.com/en/2.8.0/guide_getting-started_android_index.md.html#Getting%20Started%20with%20Android) guide for how to set up Eclipse for developing and building Phonegap apps

Comment: Is this an example of a post that is barely more than a link, and the substantial information should be posted here instead?

Comment: No, this is an example of me not duplicating the relevant information from another web page onto stackoverflow, while still answering the question. This is known as a [hyperlink](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hyperlink).

Comment: Got it. When I did the same, linking to my page, it was called "self-promotion."

Answer (score 1):

A. The **Validator** in Eclipse validates your HTML and CSS, giving filename, nature of problem, and line number of its location in the file, for all the HTML files in the app. In Eclipse, select the project name in the Package Explorer and refresh the project (File > Refresh). Watch the progress bar in the lower right. Right-click on your project name again, and select Validate. Again, watch the progress bar in the lower right. An alert will give you a quantity of problems found. To read a listing of those problems, Window > Show View > Other… > General > Problems. In addition to Problems, click on Error Log.

(If you don’t see the validation option, you’ll need to download the WTP (Eclipse Web Tools Platform). The instructions  [on this page](http://wiki.eclipse.org/WTP_FAQ#How_do_I_install_WTP.3F) will tell you how to get them. Pay special attention to the paragraph, “How do I install WTP?”)

B. Debug by using the app in a virtual device onscreen with an **emulator.** Back in the Project Explorer view, right-click on your project name, and select Debug As > Android Application. You’ll see the Console screen at the bottom of the Eclipse environment record the activity prior to appearing in the emulator.

When the emulator starts in a separate window, though, the Console will stop recording; at that point, to the right, click on the LogCat tab to see it start displaying the emulator activity. (So when you post a problem for other developers to help, this is where you’ll copy/paste from: the “LogCat” tab.)

If you have a working emulator installed, then it will launch and you’ll see the home screen. (Mine took more than a minute before it displayed, so you may need to be patient. Some have had to wait 5-10 minutes!) Drag the emulator window out of the way so you can see all the entries in LogCat.  In the emulator, drag the “lock” to the side and the app will launch after a while, if all is well. Again, be patient.

C. Right-click on the project name, choose Android Tools > **Run Lint.** This will show you, in the Lint Warnings view, problems in the Android system.